# Boost::Multi-index for nested lists

Tags: boost, nested-lists, multi-index, boost-multi-index

How to implement Boost::Multi-index on a list of lists

I have a hierarchical tree as follows:

```
typedef std::list<struct obj> objList // the object list
typedef std::list<objList> topLevelList // the list of top-level object lists

struct obj
{
   int Id; // globally unique Id
   std::string objType;
   std::string objAttributes;
   ....
   topLevelList  childObjectlist;
}
```

At the top-level, I have a std::list of struct obj
Then, each of these top-level obj can have any number of child objects,
which are contained in a topLevelList list for that object. This can continue, with a child in the nested list also having its own children.

Some objects can only be children, while others are containers and can have children of their own. Container objects have X number of sub-containers, each sub-container having its own list of child objects and that is why I have topLevelList in each obj struct, rather than simply objList.

I want to index this list of lists with boost::Multi-index to obtain random access to any of the objects in either the top-level list or the  descendant list by its globally unique Id.

Can this be accomplished? I have searched for examples with no success.

I think the only way to have a flattened master search index by object Ids is to make the lists above to be lists of pointers to the objects, then traverse the completed hierarchical list, and log into the master search index the pointer where each object is physically allocated in memory. Then any object can be located via the master search index.

With Boost::Multi-index, I'd still have to traverse the hierarchy, though hopefully with the ability to use random instead of sequential access in each list encountered, in order to find a desired object.

Using nested vectors instead of lists is a problem - as additions and deletions occur in the vectors, there is a performance penalty as well as the prospect of pointers to objects becoming invalidated as the vectors are reallocated.

I'm almost talking myself into implementing the flattened master objId search index of pointers, unless someone has a better solution that can leverage Boost::Multi-index.

**Edit on 1/31/2020:**
I'm having trouble with the implementation of nested lists below. I have cases where the code does not properly place top-level parent objects into the top level, and thus in the "bracketed" printout, we don't see the hierarchy for that parent. However, in the "Children of xxx" printout, the children of that parent do display correctly. Here is a section of main.cpp which demonstrates the problem:

```
auto it=c.insert({170}).first;
it=c.insert({171}).first;
it=c.insert({172}).first;
it=c.insert({173}).first;
auto it141=c.insert({141}).first;
    auto it137=insert_under(c,it141,{137}).first;
        insert_under(c,it137,{8});
        insert_under(c,it137,{138});
        auto it9=insert_under(c,it137,{9}).first;
            auto it5=insert_under(c,it9,{5}).first;
                insert_under(c,it5,{6});
                insert_under(c,it5,{7});
        insert_under(c,it137,{142});
        auto it143=insert_under(c,it137,{143}).first;
        insert_under(c,it143,{144});
```

If you place this code in Main.cpp instead of the demo code and run it you will see the problem. Object 141 is a parent object and is placed at the top level. But it does not print in the "Bracketed" hierarchy printout. Why is this?

**Edit on 2/2/2020:**

Boost::Serialize often delivers an exception on oarchive, complaining that re-creating a particular object would result in duplicate objects. Some archives save and re-load successfully, but many result in the error above. I have not been able yet to determine the exact conditions under which the error occurs, but I have proven that **none** of the content used to populate the nested_container and the flat object list contains duplicate object IDs. I am using text archive, not binary. Here is how I have modified the code for nested_container and also for another, separate flat object list in order to do Boost::Serialize:

```
struct obj
{
    int             id;
    const obj * parent = nullptr;

    obj()
        :id(-1)
    { }

    obj(int object)
        :id(object)
    { }

    int getObjId() const
    {
        return id;
    }

    bool operator==(obj obj2)
    {
        if (this->getObjId() == obj2.getObjId())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
#if 1
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const obj &obj);

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & id & parent;
    }
#endif
};

struct subtree_obj
{
    const obj & obj_;

    subtree_obj(const obj & ob)
        :obj_(ob)
    { }
#if 1
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const subtree_obj &obj);

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & obj_;
    }
#endif
};

struct path
{
    int         id;
    const path *next = nullptr;

    path(int ID, const path *nex)
        :id(ID), next(nex)
    { }

    path(int ID)
        :id(ID)
    { }
#if 1
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const path &pathe);

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & id & next;
    }
#endif
};

struct subtree_path
{
    const path & path_;

    subtree_path(const path & path)
        :path_(path)
    { }
#if 1
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const subtree_path &pathe);

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & path_;
    }
#endif
};

//
// My flattened object list
//

struct HMIObj
{
    int         objId;
    std::string objType;

    HMIObj()
        :objId(-1), objType("")
    { }

    bool operator==(HMIObj obj2)
    {
        if (this->getObjId() == obj2.getObjId())
            && this->getObjType() == obj2.getObjType())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    int getObjId() const
    {
        return objId;
    }

    std::string getObjType() const
    {
        return objType;
    }
#if 1
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const HMIObj &obj);

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & objId & objType;
    }
#endif
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps, you can use Boost.MultiIndex to implement a sort of hierarchical container using the notion of *path ordering*.

Suppose we have the following hierarchy of objects, identified by their IDs:

```
|-------
|      |
0      4
|----  |----
| | |  | | |
1 2 3  5 8 9
       |--
       | |
       6 7
```

We define the *path* of each object as the sequence of IDs from the root down to the object:

```
0 --> 0
1 --> 0, 1
2 --> 0, 2
3 --> 0, 3
4 --> 4
5 --> 4, 5
6 --> 4, 5, 6
7 --> 4, 5, 7
8 --> 4, 8
9 --> 4, 9
```

These paths can be ordered lexicographically so that a sequence of objects sorted by path is actually a representation of the underlying hierarchy. If we add a `parent` pointer to objects to model parent-child relationships:

```
struct obj
{
   int        id;
   const obj* parent=nullptr;
};
```

then we can define a `multi_index_container` with both O(1) access by ID and hierarchy-based indexing:

```
using nested_container=multi_index_container<
  obj,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique<member<obj,int,&obj::id>>,
    ordered_unique<identity<obj>,obj_less>
  >
>;
```

where `obj_less` compares objects according to path ordering. All types of tree manipulations and visitations are possible as exemplified below (code is not entirely trivial, feel free to ask).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0760d0251d0af07c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <iterator>

struct obj
{
   int        id;
   const obj* parent=nullptr;
};

struct subtree_obj
{
  const obj& obj_;
};

struct path
{
  int         id;
  const path* next=nullptr;
};

struct subtree_path
{
  const path& path_;
};

inline bool operator<(const path& x,const path& y)
{
       if(x.id<y.id)return true;
  else if(y.id<x.id)return false;
  else if(!x.next)  return y.next;
  else if(!y.next)  return false;
  else              return *(x.next)<*(y.next);
}

inline bool operator<(const subtree_path& sx,const path& y)
{
  const path& x=sx.path_;

       if(x.id<y.id)return true;
  else if(y.id<x.id)return false;
  else if(!x.next)  return false;
  else if(!y.next)  return false;
  else              return subtree_path{*(x.next)}<*(y.next);
}

inline bool operator<(const path& x,const subtree_path& sy)
{
  return x<sy.path_;
}

struct obj_less
{
private:
  template<typename F>
  static auto apply_to_path(const obj& x,F f)
  {
    return apply_to_path(x.parent,path{x.id},f); 
  }

  template<typename F>
  static auto apply_to_path(const obj* px,const path& x,F f)
    ->decltype(f(x))
  { 
    return !px?f(x):apply_to_path(px->parent,{px->id,&x},f);
  }

public:
  bool operator()(const obj& x,const obj& y)const
  {
    return apply_to_path(x,[&](const path& x){
      return apply_to_path(y,[&](const path& y){
        return x<y;
      });
    });
  }

  bool operator()(const subtree_obj& x,const obj& y)const
  {
    return apply_to_path(x.obj_,[&](const path& x){
      return apply_to_path(y,[&](const path& y){
        return subtree_path{x}<y;
      });
    });
  }

  bool operator()(const obj& x,const subtree_obj& y)const
  {
    return apply_to_path(x,[&](const path& x){
      return apply_to_path(y.obj_,[&](const path& y){
        return x<subtree_path{y};
      });
    });
  }
};

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using nested_container=multi_index_container<
  obj,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique<member<obj,int,&obj::id>>,
    ordered_unique<identity<obj>,obj_less>
  >
>;

template<typename Iterator>
inline auto insert_under(nested_container& c,Iterator it,obj x)
{
  x.parent=&*it;
  return c.insert(std::move(x));
}

template<typename Iterator,typename F>
void for_each_in_level(
  nested_container& c,Iterator first,Iterator last, F f)
{
  if(first==last)return;

  const obj* parent=first->parent;
  auto       first_=c.project<1>(first),
             last_=c.project<1>(last);

  do{
    f(*first_);
    auto next=std::next(first_);
    if(next->parent!=parent){
      next=c.get<1>().upper_bound(subtree_obj{*first_});
    }
    first_=next;
  }while(first_!=last_);
}

template<typename ObjPointer,typename F>
void for_each_child(nested_container& c,ObjPointer p,F f)
{
  auto [first,last]=c.get<1>().equal_range(subtree_obj{*p});
  for_each_in_level(c,std::next(first),last,f);
}

#include <iostream>

auto print=[](const obj& x){std::cout<<x.id<<" ";};

void print_subtree(nested_container& c,const obj& x)
{
  std::cout<<x.id<<" ";
  bool visited=false;
  for_each_child(c,&x,[&](const obj& x){
    if(!visited){
      std::cout<<"[ ";
      visited=true;
    }
    print_subtree(c,x);
  });
  if(visited)std::cout<<"] ";
}

int main()
{
  nested_container c;
  auto it=c.insert({0}).first;
    insert_under(c,it,{1});
    insert_under(c,it,{2});
    insert_under(c,it,{3});
  it=c.insert({4}).first;
    auto it2=insert_under(c,it,{5}).first;
      insert_under(c,it2,{6});
      insert_under(c,it2,{7});
    insert_under(c,it,{8});
    insert_under(c,it,{9});

  std::cout<<"preorder:\t";
  std::for_each(c.get<1>().begin(),c.get<1>().end(),print);  
  std::cout<<"\n"; 

  std::cout<<"top level:\t";
  for_each_in_level(c,c.get<1>().begin(),c.get<1>().end(),print);
  std::cout<<"\n"; 

  std::cout<<"children of 0:\t";
  for_each_child(c,c.find(0),print);
  std::cout<<"\n";

  std::cout<<"children of 4:\t";
  for_each_child(c,c.find(4),print);
  std::cout<<"\n";

  std::cout<<"children of 5:\t";
  for_each_child(c,c.find(5),print);
  std::cout<<"\n"; 

  std::cout<<"bracketed:\t";
  for_each_in_level(c,c.get<1>().begin(),c.get<1>().end(),[&](const obj& x){
    print_subtree(c,x);
  });
  std::cout<<"\n"; 
}
```

**Output**

```
preorder:       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
top level:      0 4 
children of 0:  1 2 3 
children of 4:  5 8 9 
children of 5:  6 7 
bracketed:      0 [ 1 2 3 ] 4 [ 5 [ 6 7 ] 8 9 ]
```

**Update 2020/02/02:**

When accessing top-level elements, I've changed the code from:

```
std::for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),...;  
for_each_in_level(c,c.begin(),c.end(),...);
```

to

```
std::for_each(c.get<1>().begin(),c.get<1>().end(),...;  
for_each_in_level(c,c.get<1>().begin(),c.get<1>().end(),...);
```

This is because index #0 is hashed and does not necessarily show elements sorted by ID.

For instance, if elements with IDs (170,171,173,173,141) are inserted in this order, index #0 lists them as

170,171,173,173,141 (coincidentally, same order as inserted),

while index #1 lists them as

141,170,171,173,173 (sorted by ID).

The way the code is implemented, `for_each_in_level(c,c.begin(),c.end(),...);` gets internally mapped to **index #1** range [170,...,173], leaving out 141. The way to make sure all top elements are included is then to write `for_each_in_level(c,c.get<1>().begin(),c.get<1>().end(),...);`.

Comment: This is wonderful! More than I had hoped for. I need to study your answer for a couple of days, and then I want to get more details on implementation. But this potentially open up some powerful functionality in my application that I would have had to try to design and implement manually. Many, many thanks!!!

Comment: Your solution opens the door to another important possibility - a meaningful step toward generalization of the patterns inherent in the hierarchical structure. For if I follow your methodology using Object Type in addition to Object ID, then I will achieve the mapping of patterns in the hierarchy - the types of objects that serve as parents and the types of objects that serve as their children, and where such patterns exist in the hierarchy. This is a major goal of my application, and you gave me a clear path forward to achieve it - pattern mapping and recognition. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Not sure I'm following your discussion on pattern mapping, but I'm glad anyway the answer was helpful  Do not hesitate to share results if you need further feedback.

Comment: I'm attempting to build your example code in order to work with it to familiarize myself with the implementation. I'm using VS2015. I get error C2059 - syntax error - empty declaration on the following line -  auto[first, last] = c.get<1>().equal_range(subtree_obj{ *p }); I haven't been able to figure out why the compiler doesn't like that line of code. Later, when you call the function for_each_child(), you're supplying the correct parameters along with a lambda to execute. Is the compiler complaining that the initialization - subtree_obj{ *p } is not acceptable?

Comment: VS2015 does not support C++17 *structured bindings*, and seemingly has some problems with default member initializers and copy list initialization. I've backported the code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/UBfJtz).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer - I have the code working. I went ahead and installed VS2017 and I also have the original code you posted working as well. I'll post questions here once I've had a chance to study the code and customize it to my needs. Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm really liking this multi-index implementation for hierarchical containers. But I have a few different functions, members of separate classes, that need to do insert() and insert_under() into the container, and the type of the iterators used is quite verbose - hence the use of "auto". But what suggestion do you have for passing these iterators to a function that needs to know the iterator for a parent in order to insert_under() that parent, for but one example? Getting the typedef for an it here is a bit challenging. A generic lambda as a vehicle to pass an it around?

Comment: `insert_under` is a function *template* accepting anything that points to an `obj`. If you absolutely need to have a concrete type you have to decide whether to use iterators for index #0 (hashed on ID) or index #1 (ordered by path). Probably index #0 makes more sense, in which case this is just `nested_container::iterator`.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with the nested container - please see my 1/31/2020 edit above.

Comment: There was a problem with the original code, just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast reply!!! I have an entire XML recursive-descent parser relying on your code for Boost::MultiIndex to save the hierarchy I parse, and this is working beautifully for my needs! This one issue which you have now resolved gets me totally un-blocked on the path toward completion of the pattern-mapping application I'm writing. I wish I could give you 1,000 UpVotes!

Comment: Your code update makes things work perfectly! I do have another, unrelated issue - I am now using Boost::Serialize to save an archive of the nested_container as well as a flattened object list that is separate from the nested_container. Often, but not always, Boost::Serialize errors-out at oarchive with a complaint that re-creating the object would result in duplicate objects. Above I post my code for the serialize feature. Are there any special considerations for serializing the nested_container?

Comment: Care to submit a separate answer? I can’t guarantee I can have a look at it tomorrow, though.

Comment: Not sure I understand - do you want me to post an entirely new question for the Boost::Serialize issue?

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041846/how-to-implement-boostserialize-for-boostnested-container

Comment: This multi-index solution for hierarchical objects is working perfectly for my application. I do have one related question on a separate multi-index container I wish to use that will be related to the hierarchical container - for multi-index containers with composite keys, must the members that comprise a composite key be adjacent members in the data structure, or can the composite key be comprised from non-adjacent members? All examples I can find show a composite key constructed from adjacent members of the data structure.

Comment: There is no such constraint: the components of a composite key can refer to non-adjacent data members in any order you need. In fact, the components need not be data members: you can specify a composite key out of `const_mem_fun` extractors, for instance.

Comment: Many thanks! What an incredibly valuable contribution you've made to C++ software engineering and development with the Boost::multi-index feature!